# seen to somebody

Tags: comprehension

Example ([Ukraine posts video of captured Russian major asking for Putin’s help](http://www.businessinsider.com/ukraine-posts-video-of-captured-russian-major-asking-for-putins-help-2015-8)):

> Moscow has also denied providing **heavy, sophisticated weaponry that has been** repeatedly **seen** in eastern Ukraine **to separatist forces**.

I've heard of the expression *to see to something* which basically means to take care of it, but it doesn't sound like what we have here is the same exact expression. Though, I might be wrong. Anyway, what do you think it means *to be seen to somebody* given the sentence's context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The '*to*' here relates to '*providing*' not to '*seen*'.

The accusation is that Moscow has been providing weapons to separatists.  This weaponry has been repeatedly seen.

The sentence could be represented as:
*Moscow has also denied providing heavy, sophisticated weaponry (that has been repeatedly seen in eastern Ukraine) to separatist forces.*

Comment: I gotcha. I just read it wrong.

Comment: @CookieMonster Note that more careful writing would have forestalled this problem: "Moscow has also denied providing separatist forces the heavy, more sophisticated weaponry . . ."